# How to set correct JAVA Memory in Centos 7.4 or Plesk Onyx

Tags: java, confluence

I have since the use of Atomicorp ASL Web and the like big problems with the JAVA memory under Centos 7.4. I have already tried many solutions from this community, but unfortunately nothing leads to success. Could you please help me.

I get this error message when I want to install Confluence App from Atlassian.

```
    ./atlassian-confluence-6.9.0-x64.bin
Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000039f25000000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Operation not permitted' (errno=1)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/bin/atlassian-confluence-6.9.0-x64.bin.764252.dir/hs_err_pid764289.log
```

I realize that it's up to Centos OS and the root server. The root server has 64 GB of RAM and Atlassian apps need about 2-4 GB of RAM on average. I certainly have free RAM left. But as I can tell JAVA, I can not get it.

Which logs do you need or which SSH commands do I have to check? Thanks in advance.

P.S.

```
tail /usr/bin/atlassian-confluence-6.9.0-x64.bin.764252.dir/hs_err_pid764289.log
tail: cannot open ‘/usr/bin/atlassian-confluence-6.9.0-x64.bin.764252.dir/hs_err_pid764289.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like you are running installer, are you running it as a root user? If no give it a try seems that installer gets failed on unpacking the JRE

Comment: Hello Saleh, Yes, this is a Linux bin installer for confluence server. With the first installation you are always on the way as root user. The problem I have but by the server reinstallation can already solve. Thank you for your time.

I also have Java 8 installed on Centos 7.4 and Plesk Onyx. That works very well now. Atomicorp ASL Web had disabled my server and many errors came after the uninstall.